# How can I remove the last character of a sentence in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, slice, morse-code

I have created an English to Morse Code translator that requires a space between each Morse Code letter. In order to do this I added an extra space after every letter in the dictionary that can be seen below.
However, this means at the end of the sentence there is an extra space (" "). Is there any way to remove this space?

I have attempted to use the str.slice function and it removes the whole morse code version of the last letter.

```
function morseCode(str) {
morseCode = {
"A": ".- ",
"B": "-... ",
"C": "-.-. ",
"D": "-.. ",
"E": ". ",
"F": "..-. ",
"G": "--. ",
"H": ".... ",
"I": ".. ",
"J": ".--- ",
"K": "-.- ",
"L": ".-.. ",
"M": "-- ",
"N": "-. ",
"O": "--- ",
"P": ".--. ",
"Q": "--.- ",
"R": ".-. ",
"S": "... ",
"T": "- ",
"U": "..- ",
"W": ".-- ",
"X": "-..- ",
"Y": "-.-- ",
"Z": "--.. ",
'1':'.---- ',
'2':'..--- ',
'3':'...-- ',
'4':'....- ',
'5':'..... ',
'6':'-.... ',
'7':'--... ',
'8':'---.. ',
'9':'----. ',}

str = str.replace(/[!,?]/g , '');

str = str.replace(/\s/g, '');

return str.toUpperCase().split("").map(el => {
   return morseCode[el] ? morseCode[el] : el;
}).join("");

};
```

Comment: use string.trim() function, it removes space at the start and end of a string

Comment: I can't help wondering why you didn't just `join(" ")` with a space rather than including the space in the alphabet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the str.slice function returns the sliced part between two index as a substring, in your case, you should use `str.slice(0,-1)`, that is equals to `str.slice(0, str.length - 1)`. And it means that is going to return every character from zero index without the last character of the string passed.

```
function morseCode(str) {
    morseCode = {
    "A": ".- ",
    "B": "-... ",
    "C": "-.-. ",
    "D": "-.. ",
    "E": ". ",
    "F": "..-. ",
    "G": "--. ",
    "H": ".... ",
    "I": ".. ",
    "J": ".--- ",
    "K": "-.- ",
    "L": ".-.. ",
    "M": "-- ",
    "N": "-. ",
    "O": "--- ",
    "P": ".--. ",
    "Q": "--.- ",
    "R": ".-. ",
    "S": "... ",
    "T": "- ",
    "U": "..- ",
    "W": ".-- ",
    "X": "-..- ",
    "Y": "-.-- ",
    "Z": "--.. ",
    '1':'.---- ',
    '2':'..--- ',
    '3':'...-- ',
    '4':'....- ',
    '5':'..... ',
    '6':'-.... ',
    '7':'--... ',
    '8':'---.. ',
    '9':'----. ',}
    
    str = str.replace(/[!,?]/g , '');
    
    str = str.replace(/\s/g, '');
    
    return str.toUpperCase().split("").map(el => {
       return morseCode[el] ? morseCode[el] : el;
    }).join("").slice(0,-1);  // this returns the string without the last character.
    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a bad practice to include spaces for values that have nothing to do with the spacing; morse code characters do not have spaces.

I recommend using `String.prototype.split()` on whatever english sentence you have, eg:

`englishSentence.split().map(englishChar => morseCodeChar[englishChar]).join(' ');`

You might have to use `.toLowerCase()` or `.toUpperCase()` or `.filter()` bad characters from the english sentence.